# JComboBox submenu items

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I believe it's possible to create submenus under JComboBoxes by creating a JMenu for the elements and so on, which in essence basically means creating your own custom component. I also looked at a few examples and it's pretty complex and most seem to have some kind of issue or other.

So basically my question is it possible to somehow in a fairly simple way create something that looks like a JComboBox but that also supports submenus.

Comment: Possible, yes, I guess; easy, I doubt it.  The biggest problem I think you would face is the fact that the items in the list are simply "rubber stamped" renderers, they aren't actual "live" components, which is going to make life very messy :P

Comment: Selection from hierarchy: Maybe [`JTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) or [`Outline`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692)?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example found in:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ComboBoxMenuExample.htm

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicArrowButton;

public class ComboBoxMenuExample extends JFrame {

  public ComboBoxMenuExample() {
  super("ComboBoxMenu Example");

String[] itemStr = { "name", "Red", "Blue", "number", "255,0,0",
    "0,0,255",
    // separator
    "system", "control", "controlHighlight", "controlShadow",
    "text"};

JMenuItem[] menuItems = new JMenuItem[7];
menuItems[0] = new JMenuItem(itemStr[1]);
menuItems[1] = new JMenuItem(itemStr[2]);
menuItems[2] = new JMenuItem(itemStr[4]);
menuItems[3] = new JMenuItem(itemStr[5]);
menuItems[4] = new JMenuItem(itemStr[8]);
menuItems[5] = new JMenuItem(itemStr[9]);
menuItems[6] = new JMenuItem(itemStr[10]);

JMenu[] menus = new JMenu[4];
menus[0] = new JMenu(itemStr[0]);
menus[1] = new JMenu(itemStr[3]);
menus[2] = new JMenu(itemStr[6]);
menus[3] = new JMenu(itemStr[7]);

menus[0].add(menuItems[0]);
menus[0].add(menuItems[1]);
menus[1].add(menuItems[2]);
menus[1].add(menuItems[3]);
menus[3].add(menuItems[4]);
menus[3].add(menuItems[5]);
menus[2].add(menus[3]);
menus[2].add(menuItems[6]);

JMenu menu = ComboMenuBar.createMenu(menuItems[0].getText());
menu.add(menus[0]);
menu.add(menus[1]);
menu.addSeparator();
menu.add(menus[2]);

ComboMenuBar comboMenu = new ComboMenuBar(menu);

JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
combo.addItem(itemStr[1]);
combo.addItem(itemStr[2]);
combo.addItem(itemStr[4]);
combo.addItem(itemStr[5]);
combo.addItem(itemStr[8]);
combo.addItem(itemStr[9]);
combo.addItem(itemStr[10]);

getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
getContentPane().add(new ComboPanel("Fake ComboBox", comboMenu));
getContentPane().add(new ComboPanel("ComboBox", combo));
}

class ComboPanel extends JPanel {
ComboPanel(String title, JComponent c) {
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  setBorder(new TitledBorder(title));
  add(c);
}
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
} catch (Exception evt) {}

ComboBoxMenuExample frame = new ComboBoxMenuExample();
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    System.exit(0);
  }
});
frame.setSize(370, 100);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}

class ComboMenuBar extends JMenuBar {

JMenu menu;

Dimension preferredSize;

public ComboMenuBar(JMenu menu) {
this.menu = menu;

Color color = UIManager.getColor("Menu.selectionBackground");
UIManager.put("Menu.selectionBackground", UIManager
    .getColor("Menu.background"));
menu.updateUI();
UIManager.put("Menu.selectionBackground", color);

MenuItemListener listener = new MenuItemListener();
setListener(menu, listener);

add(menu);
}

class MenuItemListener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  JMenuItem item = (JMenuItem) e.getSource();
  menu.setText(item.getText());
  menu.requestFocus();
}
}

private void setListener(JMenuItem item, ActionListener listener) {
if (item instanceof JMenu) {
  JMenu menu = (JMenu) item;
  int n = menu.getItemCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    setListener(menu.getItem(i), listener);
  }
} else if (item != null) { // null means separator
  item.addActionListener(listener);
}
}

public String getSelectedItem() {
return menu.getText();
}

public void setPreferredSize(Dimension size) {
preferredSize = size;
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
if (preferredSize == null) {
  Dimension sd = super.getPreferredSize();
  Dimension menuD = getItemSize(menu);
  Insets margin = menu.getMargin();
  Dimension retD = new Dimension(menuD.width, margin.top
      + margin.bottom + menuD.height);
  menu.setPreferredSize(retD);
  preferredSize = retD;
}
return preferredSize;
}

private Dimension getItemSize(JMenu menu) {
Dimension d = new Dimension(0, 0);
int n = menu.getItemCount();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  Dimension itemD;
  JMenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
  if (item instanceof JMenu) {
    itemD = getItemSize((JMenu) item);
  } else if (item != null) {
    itemD = item.getPreferredSize();
  } else {
    itemD = new Dimension(0, 0); // separator
  }
  d.width = Math.max(d.width, itemD.width);
  d.height = Math.max(d.height, itemD.height);
}
return d;
}

public static class ComboMenu extends JMenu {
ArrowIcon iconRenderer;

public ComboMenu(String label) {
  super(label);
  iconRenderer = new ArrowIcon(SwingConstants.SOUTH, true);
  setBorder(new EtchedBorder());
  setIcon(new BlankIcon(null, 11));
  setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.LEFT);
  setFocusPainted(true);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Dimension d = this.getPreferredSize();
  int x = Math.max(0, d.width - iconRenderer.getIconWidth() - 3);
  int y = Math.max(0,
      (d.height - iconRenderer.getIconHeight()) / 2 - 2);
  iconRenderer.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
}
}

public static JMenu createMenu(String label) {
return new ComboMenu(label);
}

}

class ArrowIcon implements Icon, SwingConstants {
 private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 11;

//private static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 5;

private int size;

private int iconSize;

private int direction;

private boolean isEnabled;

private BasicArrowButton iconRenderer;

public ArrowIcon(int direction, boolean isPressedView) {
this(DEFAULT_SIZE, direction, isPressedView);
}

public ArrowIcon(int iconSize, int direction, boolean isEnabled) {
this.size = iconSize / 2;
this.iconSize = iconSize;
this.direction = direction;
this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
iconRenderer = new BasicArrowButton(direction);
}

public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
iconRenderer.paintTriangle(g, x, y, size, direction, isEnabled);
}

public int getIconWidth() {
//int retCode;
switch (direction) {
case NORTH:
case SOUTH:
  return iconSize;
case EAST:
case WEST:
  return size;
}
return iconSize;
}

public int getIconHeight() {
switch (direction) {
case NORTH:
case SOUTH:
  return size;
case EAST:
case WEST:
  return iconSize;
}
return size;
}
}

class BlankIcon implements Icon {
private Color fillColor;

private int size;

public BlankIcon() {
this(null, 11);
}

public BlankIcon(Color color, int size) {
//UIManager.getColor("control")
//UIManager.getColor("controlShadow")
fillColor = color;

this.size = size;
}

public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
if (fillColor != null) {
  g.setColor(fillColor);
  g.drawRect(x, y, size - 1, size - 1);
}
}

public int getIconWidth() {
return size;
}

public int getIconHeight() {
return size;
} 
}
```

I tested here and is running perfectly
seems a little complicated, but if you take a good look at the code will understand

Comment: That's a heck of a lot of code. Perhaps you could explain how it works to the rest of us.

Comment: Or are you just posting found code that you yourself don't understand?

Comment: I found that example also while searching on Google and it's fairly complex and hardcoded. It's not really a good example for a quick solution...

Comment: The code is very clean and easy to understand. The read more than once.

An easy way to do this? When you find out let me know =)

"@ Hovercraft Full Of Eels" She asked for an example and I gave him a hint, I'm not a teacher and this is not a classroom