# problems in selecting the JComboBox items(in JMenu) Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Im having trouble in selecting the JCombox items here is a gif:
[Gif that shows exactly what is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUI3X.gif)

here is code that you can test your own as asked by @UNKNOWN
i delete everything that no needed so you can test , i have no error in console;
the code works perfectly but the combo slection error is there

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ForTest extends JFrame {
    private JTextArea txtArea= null;
    private JComboBox cmbFontSize = null;
    private JComboBox cmbFontFamily = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ForTest();
            }
        });
    }
    private ForTest(){
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("FOR TEST");
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setSize(850,500);
        txtArea= new JTextArea();
        txtArea.setSize(830,470);
        JScrollPane panScrollable = new JScrollPane(txtArea);

        panScrollable.setSize(840,480);

        this.add(panScrollable, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JMenuBar jmbTop= new JMenuBar();

        JMenu modifica = new JMenu("Modifica");
        modifica.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.PLAIN,15));
        JMenu fontSettings= new JMenu("Font Settings");
        JMenuItem cmbFam= new JMenuItem("FONT FAMILY");

        cmbFontSize = new JComboBox();
        cmbFontFamily = new JComboBox();
        cmbFam.add(cmbFontFamily);
        fontSettings.add(cmbFam);
        // fontSettings.add(cmbFontSize);
        //fontSettings.add(cmbFontFamily);
        modifica.add(fontSettings);
        jmbTop.add(modifica);
        loadFontFamily();
        loadFontSize();
        this.setJMenuBar(jmbTop);

        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void loadFontFamily() {
        String fonts[] =
                GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

        for ( int i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++ )
        {
            cmbFontFamily.addItem(fonts[i]);
        }
    }
    private void loadFontSize() {
        for (int i= 10; i<50;i++){
            cmbFontSize.addItem(i);
        }
    }
}
```

the code is simple but cant understand why i cannot select the items 
thanks in advance:)

Comment: How shall we test your code? Make a copy of your program, and eliminate everything not needed to reproduce the error. Something we can copy/paste to our system, compile and run and see ourselves. If 100 people look at your code - either you have to do the work once, or 100 people have to do the work - think about it! Think about, how likely people will test code which is easy to test, compared to code which you need to add a lot of boilerplate to make it running. And often you'll find the bug yourself, when producing such a simple demo program, believe me.

Comment: thanks sir for your answer , i have posted the code needed so you can test , it runs and complie perfectly.

Comment: That's seldom, fine response.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html . Maybe it is best, to start from the beginning of this tutorial, not just reading about the JComboBox, because it's didactically structured.

Comment: I think that this post will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576600/jcombobox-submenu-items

Comment: may the problem is space .. "Combo boxes require little screen space, and their editable (text field) form is useful for letting the user quickly choose a value without limiting the user to the displayed values. "  ... but i find it strange

Comment: @MohamedElgarnaoui hi thanks , I already saw that post and code , but it isn't that helpful I think , beacause in that case for each font family or font size I have to make n menuItems ... Combo is useful if I wouldn't find the way , probably I'll do in that way

Comment: wee i think i will go with JList , its isnt what i wanted to do but hey , they do their work :) also in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html     they suggest JList for items >20 ...                                                                             Anyway the problem for ComBoBox 90% is for Space and thanks to everyone , ill check this thread for any update:)

Comment: 1) *"HERE IS CODE.."* Ugh.. stop SHOUTING at us. To get **bold** use `**` before and after the bold text. To get *italic* use `*` before and after. Use either sparingly. 2) @userunknown Good call on asking for code we can work with (& good call on the OP for supplying same) - note that `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve].  3) `new Font("arial",Font.PLAIN,15)` would better be `new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,Font.PLAIN,15)` (OS X has no 'Arial'). 4) Best way to suggest a size for a text area is to specify rows and columns.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Thanks.  Since most people lacking complete code where never seen again, after asking for it, I didn't want to go for the SHOUTING. :) But when we at it, the mini editor with its buttons is maybe the preferred choice for most beginners, or is it disabled when browsing with noScript and noScript in such intense use? Now just - how do I remember (mcve)? Unfortunately, I didn't solved the JCmbBox problem. I never used them in the Menu, always used a toolbar for such purpose. Maybe because they vanish they lose their state?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry for my mistakes andrew,,  actually I don't wanted to write in uppercase ,I did not noticed , I will read mcve , for fonts thanks for that info . What do you mean for suggest txtarea size ? --> textArea.setSize(x,x)?

Comment: *"What do you mean for suggest txtarea size ?"* No! I meant more like `new` [`JTextArea(rows, columns)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea-int-int-). *"Sorry for my mistakes"* There's nothing to be sorry about, certainly not to me. OTOH, what I'd **prefer** to hear is more like *"Thanks for the tips. I'll do my best to make further code/posts taking those into account"* with perhaps added *"..but I don't understand the point about putting the X in the Y. How does that work?"* (much like you did in asking about setting the size of the text area).

Comment: @AndrewThompson well thanks for your tips beacuse , thanks to you I can learn more , and off course I will do my best in future , you r right there , x,y actually I don't know why I put (x,x) in my example ;)u

Comment: Huh.. I didn't even notice it repeated the x! The important point I noticed was `setSize`. If you followed the link & carefully read the docs for that constructor I suggested instead, it hopefully became obvious that cols is not the same as x, and the rows is not the same as y. The x,y is pixels, while the rows is 'no of lines' and the cols is 'characters wide' - the last is in 'quotes' because it's not completely correct unless the font is a 'fixed width' or 'monospaced' font that gives same width to an `i` as it does to a `w` (most don't). The size for rows cols also depends on font size.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the `JComboBox` inside a `JMenuItem` object and then add the  to the `JMenu` one. That would do the trick

Comment: thanks for you answert but that dosen't work same issue as that shown in the gif  ... you mean this : JMenuItem cmbFam= new 
        JMenuItem("FONT FAMILY");
        cmbFontSize = new JComboBox();
        cmbFontFamily = new JComboBox();
        cmbFam.add(cmbFontFamily);
        fontSettings.add(cmbFam); right?

Comment: @Singh: Naming it jmiFontFamily would be more consistent. :) Without being problem solving, of course.